# How can I handle the "From City" and "To City" fields dropdown text field in website mercurytravels.co.in using selenium & java

Tags: selenium, text, webdriver

I am looking to test the flight booking on the https://www.mercurytravels.co.in/flights website. I am looking to automate the "From City" and "To City" text fields. How can I select the options that get displayed?

Comment: Which is the option you wanna select ?

Answer (score 0):

to automate to and from input boxes, you can use the below code :-

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.mercurytravels.co.in/flights");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[class$='cc-dismiss']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='fromCity']"))).sendKeys("BLR");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='toCity']"))).sendKeys("DEL");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id='dpf1']"))).click();
```

also I observed, when you click there's no default options until you typed something.

Answer (score 0):

The `From City` element can be located with `input[name="fromCity"]` css selector.
Click this element, insert text containing the beginning of string the from city, f.e. "New York".
Suggested options will be presented. Click on one of them to select it.
These autocomplete options will match this XPath

```
//ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete')]//li
```

With the explicit waits of expected conditions this code can look like:

```
driver.get("https://www.mercurytravels.co.in/flights");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='fromCity']"))).sendKeys("New York");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("(//ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete')]//li)[1]"))).click();
```

The same about the "From City" field